# Change DIV Background When Nearest Radio Checked

Tags: html, jquery, css, radio-button, border

I have this already to make selecting the radio box easier

```
$("div.column43").click(function () {
$(this).find('input:radio').attr('checked', true);
});
```

I want the background/border of the div the change when radio inside it is selected.

I can get the border to change on Hover no problem but I want it to stay changed until it is deselected.

This is the format on the page

```
<div class="row43">
                <div class="column43">
                    <input id="box21" type="radio" name="box21" 
value="" checked> <label for="box21">Any/All</label>    
                </div>
                <div class="column43">
                    <label for="box22">1.0</label><input 
id="box22" type="radio" name="box21" value="1.0">
                </div>
                <div class="column43">
                    <label for="box23">1.1</label><input 
id="box23" type="radio" name="box21" value="1.1">   
                </div></div>
```

This is the css for the hover effects

```
div.row43:hover > div {
opacity: 0.5;
}
div.row43:hover > div.column43:hover {
opacity: 1.0;
}
div.row43:hover {
border-color: #0099ff;
}
div.column43:hover {
opacity: 0.5;
border-color: #0099ff;
}
```

For the life of me I cant see how to keep the border effect on when the radio is selected and the mouse is moved away.

If someone could let me know what I need to do using the actual classes that would be amazing

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can put the labels after the radio buttons you can do this purely with CSS:

```
input[type="radio"]:checked+label {
    background:#faa;
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/enE7G/)**

If not, using jQuery you can do it like this:

```
$("div.column43").click(function () {
    $(this).parent('div.row43').find('label').removeClass('highlight');
    $(this).find('input:radio').attr('checked', true);
    $(this).find('label').addClass('highlight');
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/enE7G/1/)**

Comment: this i tried before but it only changes the background of the text. I want the exact same thing but changing the border &/or background of the DIV

Comment: I'm not clear, are you saying the background only changes in the jsFiddles for you, or in your own code and the jsFiddles work?

Comment: hi! the effect is the same on jfiddle and on my site. Only the text background changes

Comment: Both the background and border change in both fiddles. Not sure why you'r not seeing it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this with:

```
$(':radio:checked').closest('div').addClass('selected');
```

or using with `.css()`:

```
$(':radio:checked').closest('div').css({
                                        'border':'solid 1px red', 
                                        'background': '#e2e2e2'
                                       });
```

Finally this should be like this: **[checkout fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hs7Br/)**

```
$(':radio').change(function () {
    $(this).parent().removeClass('selected');
    $(':radio:checked').closest('div').addClass('selected');
});
```

Comment: How does you answer address the question: "I want the background/border of the div the change when radio inside it is selected."?

Comment: jai, this is progress but looking at the Fiddle example is does not deselect

Comment: @jai this is the best so far, it highlights the div but only if you use the word "checked" clicking does not do anything :-(
     $(':radio:checked').closest('div').css({
                                        'border':'solid 1px red', 
                                        'background': '#e2e2e2'
                                       });

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an event for the radio buttons and then set the background-color of the parent.

```
$('div.column43').find('input[type=radio]').change(function() {
  if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
    $(this).parent().css('background-color', 'red'));
  }
});
```

Comment: This does not work at all but it does stop me being able to click anywhere in the DIV to select the radio